# Efficiently fusing (or merging/combining) two points geometry data sets

Tags: python, postgis, postgresql, point

I haven't found good suggestions while googling "*GIS fusion of two points geometry data sets*" so I am here to seek suggestions for my data fusion problem.

I have two points table in my PostgreSQL 11 database (Windows 10, x64). Table 1 `tbl1` is a points data set (let say, building polygons centroid), containing `Gid,X,Y,val1,geom`. Table 2 is another points (2 meter points) data set (let say, road/linestrings split into 2 m points), containing `Gid,X,Y,val2,geom`. The points in `tbl1` are at irregular distance from those in `tbl2`. Some screenshots of the different scenarios can be seen below.

Assuming `val1` in Table 1 is the reference value (or having a higher weightage), for each point in Table 1, I want to fuse/merge/combine `val1` value with `val2` in Table 2, yielding a new/fused output. I am not sure about considering (or not considering) the distance between the two points data sets and directionality, though the data (both table) reflect a so-called realistic urban landscape.

How can I fuse the above two data sets?

Note: Pink = reference points. Green = to be merged/fused with the pinkies

**EDIT 1:**

Let say, if i start by taking a max value (val2) of all Table 2's points within 15 m of each Table 1's point:

```
Select distinct on (a.id)
    a.id,
    a.val1::int val1,
    max(b.val2) val2,
    a.geom
From
    tbl1 a
left join tbl2 b on
st_dwithin(a.geom, b.geom, 15)
group by a.id, a.val1, a.geom
order by a.id;
```

Then I get something like (`geom` column omitted here):

```
id    val1     val2
1     11       13
2     11       13
3     15       19
4     16       14
......
```

How do I "fuse" column 2 and column 3 to get an optimal value (new column 4) (taking column 2 as reference)?

[image]

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by fusing, if you add a code attempt it might be clearer. How about [union](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-union/)?

Comment: Thanks for your interest. I do not want to do a simple UNION or UNION ALL that merges/combines rows of two tables by taking care of duplicated/non-duplicated rows. I want to combine ("fuse") val1 and val2 of the two tables, which are spatially different, by taking val1 as a reference value. Makes sense? Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Please val1 and val2 are not the same all the time. They can be close to each other but not the same.

Comment: @BERA: Added. Hope it gives you some idea, merging/combining two spatial data sets, but it's not a simple union or average problem.

Comment: Still unclear. What value are you expecting in column 4? 11,11,15,16? What do you want to do with the geometries? Create one multipoint per row?

Comment: @BERA: Excellent question. That is where is the fusion part is, and the main point of this question. I would like to fuse val2 to my val1. You can think of val1 as a static, near-reliable (reference) value, which i don't to disturb much. In addition, one can think of val2 as 'dynamics' part but with a possibility of a little noise in it.

Comment: That said, I would not expect the column 4 to be complete opposite of column 2 (val1). I would still expect column 4 to be close to column 1, but still somehow does not neglect column 3 :) sorry, if it is becoming too complicated. I noticed some Python libraries like fuzzy matches, integration and filtering, etc. I am not sure if they exist in SQL, and what can be the optimal approach to fuse/merge the data.

Comment: @BERA: I forgot to mention, I would like to keep the table 1 geometry. That is, each point (row) having val1, val2 (max within 15 m), and the fused/merged value.

Comment: You question is very unclear.  It would be helpful to provide an example of the output you are trying to produce.  Yes postgres has fuzzy matching for strings.  I don't really think that's what you need here, but again, it's not clear what you are trying to achieve.  I think you might need clustering.  Look at st_clusterwithin and st_clusterdbscan.

Comment: @jbalk: My bad for being still unclear. I tried to explain in the above comments what I am looking for, e.g. Fuzzy integration or any data fusion technique to combine column 2 and 3, keeping column 2 as a reference (with higher weightage). I am not sure how clustering can help to combine those two columns. In the output, i just expect a merged column and table 1 geometry in addition to the columns shown in the above query output.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by 'combine column 2 and 3'.  There are lots of ways to combine columns...  You have integer values in the columns - what do you want to do with them?  Add them?  Aggregate them into an array?  Keep one of them over the other??  These things are unclear.  In your example table, for id 1, what do you expect to end up with in column 4?  How would you 'combine' val1 and val2 to get the value for column 4?

Comment: @jbalk: I appreciate your curiosity. For each ID, I want to fuse both values to have an output closer to val1. Does it make sense and clear now? One may call it data merging or combining or data fusion, it doesn't matter much. I was looking for more sophisticated way of doing this instead of simple aggregation (mean, median), etc. There are several data fusion techniques exist in R, python, e.g. fuzzy integration (Choquet Integral), Kalman filtering, Bayesian filtering.. I am not sure if such things exist in SQL or one has to dumb data in SQL and use python to do the science.

Comment: So I tagged python as well in the question.

Comment: I'm sorry but it's still not clear.  A specific example of a RESULT that you expect would help.  You just mentioned Choquet Integral in your comment.  Why don't you just use that formula in your sql?

Comment: @jbalk: That's because I couldn't find relevant SQL example or solution (Choquet Integral). Care to post a suggestion how that can be implemented for each ID?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RFDuUvYxGNo. A suggestion for what problem exactly?  You haven't clarified the problem or expected output.  What is 'optimal value'?

Comment: @jbalk: :) The problem: I want to apply fuzzy integration (Choquet Integral) to column 2 and 3 for each row/ID, and the expected is obviously the integrated output. Makes sense? Thanks for the video link. Let's forget the optimal value :)